# What happened to this character since we last saw him?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In episode S06E11 of the anime *My Hero Academia*,

> Best Jeanist returned to fight agains All For One and Shigaraki.
>  But didn't he lose his quirk with AFO stealing it before? He did use some metal wires to constrict Gigantomachia, so he is surely using some quirk, but what exactly?
>  If Eri could return stolen quirks, then she would have helped Ragdoll get her search ability too. So, it doesn't seem like Eri's doing.

So, how could this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His quirk wasn't stolen by All For One: in the fight he got hit by an air cannon for AFO and taken out of the fight (S03E10).

AFO didn't take Jeanist's quirk because he thought it was inherently weak and was only "strong" through all the practice and skill Best Jeanist developed through hard work and training.

[Reference + Manga chapter 89](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/All_For_One_(Quirk)#:%7E:text=The%20effectiveness%20of%20the%20Quirks,steal%20Quirks%20with%20straightforward%20abilities.)

> [All For One] Now I see ...
> Your strength comes from practice and practical experience, not raw power.
> I don't need your quirk
> <sub>(MHA S03E10, English dub)</sub>

Comment: oh yeah, now I remember AFO saying something distasteful about Jeanist's Quirk.. and therefore he didn't wanted to take his quirk. Thanks for the clarification!